# Asking questions about advantages & disadvantages on SO?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

This question related to: [**How to ask**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Is it good choice by asking questions that compare between two topics(advantages and disadvantages on each side), I'm feeling confused of asking a question like this on SO.

Comment: In general, no. Often such questions are of the [Gorilla vs Shark](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) type.

Comment: Have you ever heard the phrase "One man's trash is another man's treasure."? A list of advantages & disadvantages is more often than not a matter of opinion, and thus a terrible question (for SO).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your question wants people to list reasons to use X or not use X, it's off-topic. We do much better when there are specific problems to be solved.

Tell us what problem you're trying to solve. Deciding which framework/language/tool to use to solve that problem isn't something we can help you with. It does not fit well into our format.

Helping you implement whatever you're trying to implement with framework/language/tool *is* something we can help you solve.

Answer (score 3):

If they satisfy the requirements in [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), then you can ask them.

**Be prepared that in most cases they do not.** "PHP vs Ruby" style questions are about opinions, not expertise. Questions asking to collect advantages and disadvantages are too broad in most cases (and involve opinions), and invite polling-style answers.

If you are unsure, don't ask. If you ask, don't be attached to the question too much.

Comment: "If they satisfy the requirements...etc" Does this type of questions satisfy the requirements?

Comment: @MoathHowari If you want a general answer, then no.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I agree and I upvoted your answer. I wrote what I wrote because I can imagine a situation when the issue is specific enough that it can be answered in a reasonable way. Comparing cannot only happen between languages, tools, etc.