# Question about advantages is high quality?

Tags: discussion

I just reviewed some first posts, when I encountered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42829977/predicate-vs-if-statement). The question asks for a list of advantages and disadvantages. Since such a question cannot be answered in a *correct* way and does not really tackle a concrete problem, I flagged it as **primarly opinion-based**.

The review appeared to be [a test](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/15763741) and I got the message:

> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You didn't pass. Your review was inappropriate. This was a high quality post and you should have considered leaving it as-is or even upvoting.

As a reaction, I searched through Meta and found [a question on this topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258308/asking-questions-about-advantages-disadvantages-on-so). The accepted answer (from a moderator) says:

> If your question wants people to list reasons to use X or not use X, it's off-topic.

Maybe I should've flagged the post as **off-topic**, but there would be no difference, because the system thinks of the question as a high-quality question and expects at least leaving it as-is.

Is this correct and intended?

Comment: It's a bad audit IMO. Question is off-topic and is POB. You would have failed for flagging as well unfortunately. I would flag outside the audit as the question _should_ be closed.

Comment: I did flag it in audit and got blocked for 8 days. My previous wrong audits were kinda borderline in my opinion, so I accepted the block and moved on. But this time I searched Meta and it proved me right, so I wanted to ask.

Comment: The answer to the linked possible duplicate says: "You've done the right thing in bringing attention to this poor audit by posting this question." So, should this question be closed? Should every bad audit lead to a Meta question or not? Maybe one could think about an additional review queue for reported _bad audits_, where users can vote for the deactivation of blocks caused by the audit.

Comment: I've never come across this "audit" concept before, but if anyone thinks it legitimate to waste my time by asking pseudo-questions designed to test me, I would deeply resent it. We're volunteers, we don't take part in SO to be tested in this way.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Some people don't do it just to be helpful. Some people treat it like a game, and some people start out being helpful but end up being lazy. It isn't meant to be an insult to you; it's just hard for a robot to tell if you happen to be someone who always pays attention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I generally prefer "Too Broad" for any question asking for an exhaustive list of differences between two things, but in this case Primarily Opinion Based seems appropriate too, as whether a difference is a "pro" or a "con" is an opinion, and of course the actual answers are just full of people giving their opinions on "which one they like better" (nobody is even trying to actually answer the question asked of what the pros and cons are) so I certainly wouldn't have any problem at all with Primarily Opinion Based.

Of course, many people find these opinion based questions highly *entertaining*, despite the fact that they don't belong here, so they can attract lots of upvotes, and many people don't downvote them despite the fact that they're off topic, which occasionally results in a question like this becoming an audit.

Comment: Is there any way to report this audit? Should I have used the __bug__ tag, because in my opinion, it should be removed instead of just being discussed.

Comment: @lukegv Just downvote the post and vote to close it.  That alone will make it ineligible as an audit.  In this case, others have already done as much, so it's already no longer an eligible audit.

Comment: I downvoted it and also applied a _real_ flag, but I don't have enough reputation to vote for closing.